# translate excel equation to matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, if-statement, excel-formula

I need help translating an excel equation to matlab.

I have translated a simple if-statements in excel such as:

```
Ps(t)=IF(T(t)<Tp,P,0)
```

into matlab as:

```
 if Ps(t)=T(t)<Tp;              
 p;
 0;
 end
```

Is this correct? and if so how do I translate a more complicated excel equation such as:

```
=IF(F6>273.16,(IF(AND(AB5>0,Y6>0),MIN(Y6*3600/$AE$11,AB5),0)),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Ps(t)=IF(T(t)<Tp,P,0)` in Excel then in Matlab you could do:

```
Ps = zeros(1, length(T));
Ps(T<Tp) = p;
```

where T is a vector.
This reads, define `Ps` as an array of zeros having the same length as `T`. For those indexes of `T` where `T(i)<Tp` set those in Ps to `p`.  This is logical indexing.

The other expression:

```
=IF(F6>273.16,(IF(AND(AB5>0,Y6>0),MIN(Y6*3600/$AE$11,AB5),0)),0)
```

has to be analyzed in terms of how this equation operates in Excel. Is this formula copied along the rows of the same column?
From which cell is this formula?

Let's say this was taken from cell J6, then iterating over row i you get:

```
AE11 = 100; %this is the constant from cell AE11

for i= 2:length(F)
    if F(i) > 273.16
      if  AB(i) > 0 & Y(i) >0;
        J(i) = min( Y(i)*3600/ AE11 ,AB(i-1));
      else
        J(i) = 0;
      end
    else
      J(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

This could be improved with a vectorized version, even though there seems to be a reference to a different row (AE5, when everything is about row 6).

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  Would you be able/willing to help translate one more equation from excel to matlab? I'll add the next problem as an answer to this initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(M5>$AD$17,$AD$5+$AD$8,IF(N5>0,$AD$5+(O4-$AD$5)*EXP((IF(F5>273.16,$AD$11,$AD$14))*0.04167),0))
```

How would this excel equation be translated to matlab? I am very unclear of how to handle the final nested If statement.

Comment: As above, you have nested ifs, so translate them as before. Any column row combination is an element of an array in Matlab ( M5 -> M(i) ). Identify Excel constants ($AD$14). If you have different rows then respect that (N5 and O4 should become N(i) and O(i-1) )